# Convert a IplImage* type to CvMat

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to convert Image from IplImage* to CvMat* to use cvCountNonZero.. to  find white area in a Black and white image instead of using two for loops (which is slow)..

Answer (score 2):

**Code snippet found [here](http://wangpengnorman.blogspot.com/2009/06/transform-between-cvmat-and-iplimage.html):**

```
CvMat stub, *dst_mat;
dst_mat = cvGetMat(src_img, &stub, 0, 0);
```